# Variables, functions and class scope in PHP OOP

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm a quite noobie in PHP. I've created a class with a function that will pass my parameters for checking if is some field empty or not.

I've many declared variables, so I don't want to repeat code again and again.

For example:
In `file1.php` I have this class:

```
class wow {
    public $emptyString = '';
    public $data;

    function emptyValue($emptyString, $data) {
        $empty = empty($data) ? $emptyString : $data;
        echo $empty;
    }
}
$wow = new wow();
```

And in `file2.php` I call the function:

```
include 'file1.php';
$header_first_icon_title = get_field ('header_first_icon_title');

$wow->emptyValue('Field is empty', $header_first_icon_title );
```

This only works when I declare `$header_first_icon_title = get_field ('header_first_icon_title');` right to the `$wow->emptyValue('Field is empty', $header_first_icon_title );`
Literally in one line above.

If I declare `$header_first_icon_title = get_field ('header_first_icon_title');` on the top of the file, and I call `$wow->emptyValue('Field is empty', $header_first_icon_title );` for example after 2, 3 houndres of html lines this will not catch the `$data`. It will only return "Field is empty".

I'm not sure why this happens. I don't get any errors. 
I want to declare all variables on the top, so I can call them where I need them later in the file.

If someone can help me/explain to me why this has this behavior I would be more then thankful.

Comment: Where did you declared the function `get_field`?

Comment: Wrote a minimized version of your code and then moved the `$header_first_icon_title` assignment to the top. Nothing is wrong with it: [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7eef830c8f8e1e2fdc252d59c46e92580e8cf88c)

Comment: @KoalaYeung `get_field` function is a function from the `Advanced Custom Field` plugin. You can see documentation [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)  I forgot to mention that this is related to the `WordPress theme developing`. 

I'm not sure that I understand this second part which you talking about.

Comment: I found a solution so when I add `$wow->emptyValue('Field is empty', get_field ('header_first_icon_title') );` it works. 

But still, I don't get it why they don't work when is declared in the variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "declared in the variable"?

Comment: @KoalaYeung For example:
I have three fields with the name `header_name`, `title_name` and `footer_name`

I want to declare them all in variables, so:

`$header_name = get_fields('header_name');`
`$title_name = get_fields('title_name');`
`$footer_name = get_fields('footer_name');`

After that they need to be passed through the function:

`$wow->emptyValue('Field is empty', $header_name );`


And there is a problem from my question.

Comment: Without the full source code, its really hard to grasp the context of the whole issue. It's mostly likely have to do with scoping in PHP. PHP, by default, is a local scope language. Unless otherwise specified (e.g. with `global` keyword), variable dies when the function scope end.

Comment: I can only guess that your variable definition (i.e. `$header_name = get_fields('header_name');`) and the statement (i.e. `$wow->emptyValue('Field is empty', $header_name );`) are in different blocks so the later line do not have access to the variable declared earlier.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I tried to put all var in `global` but the problem still persists. 

I found, for now, a temporary solution, but I will definitely dig more into the problem. 

Thanks for your try to help me.

Comment: You should not put all variables in `global`. That's a really bad practice. Also if one of them is using the global scope `$header_name` but the other is not, they are still reading different variables (which is very common mistake for first-time Wordpress plugin developers). By default, plugin files are not in the global scope.

Comment: @KoalaYeung So, do you suggest what should I try?

Comment: You should start by investigating the scope where you declare and use the variables. Use [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to see how a line is invoked.